# Setting sql server php pdo xampp on mac os x el-capitan [Laravel]

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, laravel, xampp

i've been do lot of tutorial that i found on internet to install sql server php pdo xampp on mac os x el-capitan but not working at all.

do you have any tutorial or step by step to do to solve my problem?
thanks a lot

Comment: I doubt it makes sense to point you to another tutorial, since you claim you already "did a lot" of them. Why should simply trying the next one suddenly succeed? Instead I would suggest that you tell us _why_ all those attempts you made failed, so what your actual problem (with them) was.

Comment: dont know. all tutorial that i do doesnt give me error. but still not detect the driver of sql server
i've tried using freetds in this website
https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/wiki/Mac-setup-to-connect-to-a-MS-SQL-Server
http://lkrms.org/php-with-freetds-on-os-x-mavericks/
https://dunglas.fr/2014/01/connection-to-a-ms-sql-server-from-symfony-doctrine-on-mac-or-linux/

+arkascha

Comment: What do you mean by "driver"? Are the sql server, the http server and the php engine installed and usable or not?

Comment: based in this picture http://imgur.com/IK3oNSu
the http server worked normally, its like enable postgree driver on php.ini but in "sql server" case its more complicated